# UWP App Background Task Not Able to write to JSON File

Tags: json, json.net, uwp

I am trying to read and write to a JSON file present in my windows 10 run time component project.

I am able to read data from the JSON file but not able to write to the JSON file.

It gives error access denied.

can't i read a JSON file from the project folder or there is a way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What is project folder, do you mean "..Current.InstalledLocation..", or what? Add please your code for writing in JSON.

Comment: A piece of code would be very helpful...

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to write to project folder in UWP apps, as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) says:

> ..The app's install directory is a read-only location..

Try to use LocalFolder as storage for file instead of project folder:

```
//save file to local folder
await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("your.json");
//get file from local
var item = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("your.json") as StorageFile;
```